# How to get the max TCP socket buffer size in QNX

Tags: sockets, tcp, qnx

Is it possible to get and set the max tcp socket buffer size via command line in QNX?
if not how can I do it with c++?

Answer (score 0):

The [sysctl command](http://www.qnx.com/developers/docs/7.1/#com.qnx.doc.neutrino.utilities/topic/s/sysctl.html) can be used at the command line to adjust the maximum socket buffer size at the command line - see `kern.sbmax`.  The [sysctl function](http://www.qnx.com/developers/docs/7.1/index.html#com.qnx.doc.neutrino.lib_ref/topic/s/sysctl.html) can be used in software to make programmatic changes to sysctl entries.